# Android Animation and transitioning

Tags: android, transition

The code below is supposed to:

When the I touch the screen the button moves from top-left to right-bottom. And if I touch the screen again then the button will move from right-bottom to top-left.

But what is happening is that when I touch the screen the button starts moving from TL to BR but then it jumps right back to the TL corner!

The longer I touch the screen the longer button "travels" towards the BL corner.
Why is that? And what must I change in order for the button to move in one direction the 1st time I touch the screen, and in the other direction the 2nd time I touch?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    state = false;
    myLayout = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
    myLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            moveButton();
            return true;
        }
    });
}

public   void moveButton() {
        View theButton = findViewById(R.id.button1);

        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(myLayout); //for smooth transitioning

        //Change position
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams posRules = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        if ( state)         {
            posRules.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
            posRules.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);

        }
        else {
            posRules.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
            posRules.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        }

        theButton.setLayoutParams(posRules);

        //Change size
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams sizeRules = theButton.getLayoutParams();
        if ( state) {
            sizeRules.width = 250;
            sizeRules.height = 100;

        }
        else {
            sizeRules.width = 450;
            sizeRules.height = 300;
        }
        theButton.setLayoutParams(sizeRules);

        state = !state;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onTouchListener` is called for every touch event. For example, when you touch the screen an `ACTION_DOWN` is sent. When your finger lifts up, an `ACTION_UP` is sent. You can find an explanation of all the events [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#constants).

Right now you are getting at least two calls to `onTouchListener` each time you touch the screen. To have it only animate once per touch, I would do something like the following to only execute on the down touch event.

```
myLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            moveButton();
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```